# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with @Input decorator

Tags: angular

I have a child component that receives data via @Input() decorator. My goal is to create a new Object with arrays from the parent component data. I receive data but for some reason I can't use `map()` method with this data, here is my TS component part:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import {Group} from "@models/group.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-group-admins',
  templateUrl: './group-admins.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./group-admins.component.css']
})
export class GroupAdminsComponent implements OnInit {
  admins: Array<Group> = [];
  new_admins = []
  @Input('group')
  set _group(value) {
    this.admins = value;
    this.new_admins = value.users.map(a => ({id: a.user, permissions: a.permissions}));
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.new_admins = this.admins.users.map(a => ({id: a.user, permissions: a.permissions}));
  }
}
```

And Group model just for reference:

```
import {GroupUser} from "@models/group-user.model";

export class Group {
  id: string;
  group_name: string;
  type: string;
  avatar?: string;
  header?: string;
  address?: string;
  date?: string;
  city?: string;
  about?: string;
  verify_status?: string;
  site?: string;
  phone?: string;
  email?: string;
  web_site?: string;
  industry?: true;
  directions_list?: string;
  users: Array<GroupUser>
}
```

Also I can't do it in ngOnInit part. I'm sure that I receive data from @Input() because I can `console.log` it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are indeed receiving data, otherwise it would say `cannot read property 'users' of undefined`. You should check if `users` is really set in the data you receive

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed receiving data, otherwise it would say `cannot read property 'users' of undefined`. You should check if `users` is really set in the data you receive. Also, the typings of your `admins` field is set to `Array<Group>`, but in the `@Input()` you seem to be expecting just a `Group` object, not an array, even though you do assign this to `this.admins`.

So there are two possibilities

1. The `.users` property is not set in the `group` you bind to the component
2. The `group` input receives an array and `users` does not exist on an `Array`, so it errors.

For both cases you have to look, but most likely you do not want to pass in an array of groups to the component, but just a single group, which means you should look at the parent template to fix it